# Database error when I uploaded my laravel project on AWS which was working fine in development

Tags: mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services, sqlite

I am just a beginner so this problem might be stupid.
I was using sqlite while developing and when I uploaded my project on AWS I got this error:-

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'f2bbac78-d85f-42fd-ba4c-276c2d9ee2b6' for column 'confessedTo' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `confessions` (`confession`, `confessedTo`, `confessionFrom`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (AFCASCASCa, f2bbac78-d85f-42fd-ba4c-276c2d9ee2b6, 1, 2020-11-30 08:02:09, 2020-11-30 08:02:09))

**Here's that Table:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('confessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('confessedTo');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('confessionFrom');
            $table->text('confession');
            $table->string('name')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

is it because I am passing a `uuid` which is `f2bbac78-d85f-42fd-ba4c-276c2d9ee2b6` this type of data in my `confessedTo` column?.

 Please help

**Edits**
I have changed the attribute to `uuid` in all my tables but one tables does not seems to be working fine which is listed below:-

**Before:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('from')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('to')->unsigned();
            $table->text('text');   
            $table->string('list_no')->nullable(); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**After:-**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->uuid('from');
            $table->uuid('to');
            $table->text('text');   
            $table->string('list_no')->nullable(); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is from where my unread messages are coming from:-

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('read')->after('to')->default(false);
        });
    }
```

**Error:-**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'read' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `from` as sender_id, count(`from`) as messages_count from `messages` where `to` = f2bbac78-d85f-42fd-ba4c-276c2d9ee2b6 and `read` = 0 group by `from`)

Please Help..

Comment: Yes. Teh `confessedTo` colum accepts only integers. But you are passing a string with mixed charectors. So make that column as uuid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should change your `confessedTo` column type to `uuid` or use integer values instead of `uuid`.

```php
$table->uuid('confessedTo');
```

Reference: [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-columns)

Comment: I did change it to uuid in all my tables but it is not working in one of my table, i have updates it in my question please help

Comment: Did you refresh your migrations after changing the migration files?